# How to correctly display my informations?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

In my application, there are logs with levels : Info, Debug, Warning, Error.
I've done a warning counter, with all logs at this level.
I managed to show the counter in a stackpanel with a custom flag.

Actually, all logs are displayed in a tooltip, when the mouse is over the counter.
The issue is that the focus isn't working, so I need to find a component to correct that.

The aim is that the user read all logs, the value of the counter is 0 and the list of logs is empty.

Which component to use to solve my issue ?
I can redefine the parent stackpanel if needed.

Comment: very confusing question! put some printscreens or so in order to make us understand better what you're problem is

Answer (score 0):

you can put a user control in popup control and manipulate the IsOpen property

```
<Popup x:Name="LoginUiPopup" Placement="Center" IsOpen="True" StaysOpen="True" >            
        <ContentControl>
            <Grid>

            </Grid>
        </ContentControl>
</Popup>
```

you can binding IsOpen property with log count.